# Onclcik ng-show not showing the data in accordion using angularJS and Ionic?

Tags: angularjs

I have tow api one return clinics list and another is onclcik take the clinic id and call the api and display the data to that particular id in accordion list.

But by using ng-show, I am unable to show the data.

Here is my code:

**Html code:**

```
<ion-list id = "background">
        <div id = "background"  >
          <ion-item class="item-stable item item-avatar"  ng-click = "select(list.ClinicId);" ng-repeat="list in searchlist">
            <img ng-src = "img/1.png"/>
            <!--  &nbsp; -->
            {{list.Name}}
            &nbsp;
            <p> Address: {{list.Address.Address1}},  {{list.Address.Address2}},  {{list.Address.Postcode}},  {{list.Address.State}},  {{list.Address.Suburb}}</p> 
            </ion-item  >
            <ion-item class="item-accordion"  ng-show="isSelected();" ng-repeat="available in appointments" >
              {{available.Appointments.Name}} {{available.Appointments.Speciality}}
            </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
            api.AvailableAppointments(item)
                .success(function(data) {
                $scope.availableappointments = data;
                console.log(data);
                window.sessionStorage['availableappointments'] = angular.toJson(data);
                var appointments = window.sessionStorage['availableappointments'];
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
              };
  $scope.isSelected = function() {
        var appointments = window.sessionStorage['availableappointments'];
        $scope.appointments = angular.fromJson(accessData); 
        console.log($scope.appointments);
    };
```

please tell me where I am going wrong....[image]

Comment: Does ´list.ClinicId´ correspond to the ID that has been selectionned ?

Comment: yes, I am taking this id from one api response and I have to pass this id into another API as url  and take the data for corresponding to that id and display in accordion

Comment: display the list as in image that I have upload is "ng-repeat="list in searchlist"" by this and from this response I am taking the id of particular clinic and onclick I am passing the id in this function "ng-click = "select(list.ClinicId);"" and I am getting the response, but I am not able to display in accordion

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great to have a plunker document join to your question but I might an idea why it doesn't work.

Your `isSelected()` function return nothing that might be why it doesn't change.
Try to add the $index as an argument of your function and compare it to the active clinicID (the one that has been clicked ) then return the answer.

**.html**

```
        <ion-item class="item-accordion"  ng-show="isSelected($index);" ng-repeat="available in appointments" >
          {{available.Appointments.Name}} {{available.Appointments.Speciality}}
        </ion-item>
```

**.js**

```
  $scope.isSelected = function(itemIndex) {
        var appointments = window.sessionStorage['availableappointments'];
        $scope.appointments = angular.fromJson(accessData); 
        console.log($scope.appointments);
        return (itemIndex == itemSelectionnedIndex);
    };
```

If it doesn't work if `ng-show` try with `ng-if`

**Edit :**
I try to adapt your code on the example that you gave me :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdjAn

You only have to adapt the code to make hide the second accordion when you click a second time.
But it should work...
And your main problems (from what I saw in your code) was that you isSelected returned nothing and your appointments variable is not a list.

Hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: Prolem is that from this reponse of this function  "ng-click = "select(list.ClinicId);"", clinicid is not there so I can not match id with this response "$scope.appointments"

Comment: Can I see an example of your json data ? That would help to understand.

Comment: You can also create a $scope.active to keep the active index then match it with the index of the item.

Comment: this is the response I am getting after onclcick and I want to display this data in accordion {"Appointments":[{"DoctorId":2,"Name":"Dr. Hasacure","Speciality":"General Practitioner","Appointments":[{"AppointmentTime":"2014-09-29T08:30:00+00:00","Duration":900,"Available":true},{"AppointmentTime":"2014-09-29T08:45:00+00:00","Duration":900,"Available":true}]},{"DoctorId":2,"Name":"Dr. Findacure","Speciality":"General Practitioner","Appointments":[{"AppointmentTime":"2014-09-29T13:30:00+00:00","Duration":900,"Available":true},]}]}

Comment: Clinic Id I am taking from here[{"ClinicId":1,"Name":"Test Clinic ABC","Address":{"Address1":"unit 87","Address2":"50 Gold Coast Hwy","State":"QLD","Suburb":"Palm Beach","Postcode":"1223"},"GroupId":0,"Appointments":{"Appointments":[]}},{"ClinicId":2,"Name":"Test Clinic PCB 1","Address":{"Address1":"unit 223","Address2":"1345 Gold Coast Hwy","State":"QLD","Suburb":"Burleigh Heads","Postcode":"2344"},"GroupId":1,"Appointments":{"Appointments":[]}}]

Comment: Ok your json answer is not valid... Try on this site to see http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Both json response is valid

Comment: I am not able to post my code on plunker because of this error " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access. " to remove this error I am using bat file...

Comment: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz see this link, I want exactly like this but with api call.... place of group, I want to display the "Clinic List" and click on that particular clinic accordion open and show the detail, for both clinic list and get the detail of that particular clinic I have to different api